# dbf file created in c# can not open in dbase

Tags: dbf, dbase

i created a file .dbf with C# code in using OdbcConnection, but when i want to open it with dbase, it says that's not a dbf file, could anyone explain me why and how it could work ?

Comment: There are different versions of file headers associated with database files... dBase, FoxPro (old version) and Visual FoxPro.   Can you show us the connection (hide otherwise private path info), and the command you used to create the table.  Also, are you really trying to open from dBASE?  Which version too.

Comment: I have to open it with dBase because another application(created 25 years ago, under DOS) also use it. The Connection is ODBCConnection(DSN=CodeBase;DBQ=C:\Temp) and The commande is CREATE TABLE CENTRALE (DATE DATE, PERS NUMERIC(5,0), SERVICE NUMERIC(12,2))

Comment: In fact, i have to modify the structure of a table, as i can not use ALTER TABLE, i have to DROP and CREATE the table with colum added, but every time i create, the DBF file is damaged... not only DBase can not open it, but it's totaly interrupted....

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it sounds like something from dBase III Plus.  I don't even believe ODBC even existed back in late 80's, early 90's.  Going back that far, dBASE didn't even have "Databases", but all the tables were actually free on their own, and as the developer, you would code your relationships to add records, establish keys, etc.

What you may want to do instead is to just create a table based on the format you expect directly from dBASE and just put it empty in a holding folder.  Then, when you need it, copy to the destination directory and run from there.

A second option...  Go to Microsoft and download their "VFP Ole DB provider" and try using that.  You can also try doing an ExecNonQuery and try something like

```
use SomeTable
copy to YourNewTable type foxplus
```

which might be the closest output to match that of dBase.